# Dependency Injection: Separating the Call Graph from the Construction Graph

Tags: dependency-injection, call-graph

I'm trying to exercise the [principles of Dependency Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection), and I'm having some difficulty doing so.

I have a function that periodically goes off to my database, retrieves a list of products, and then runs a battery of tests against those products in order to determine their safety.

If one or more of the products is found to be unsafe, I need to issue a recall by instantiating and dispatching a `ProductRecall` object.

The function looks something like this: (pseudo-code)

```
void SafteyInspector::CheckProductSaftey()
{
  database.getProducts( list_of_products )

  foreach( list_of_products as p )
  {
    if ( !runBatteryOfTests( p ) )
      unsafe_products.insert( p );
  }

  if ( !unsafe_products.empty() )
  {
    ProductRecall * recall = 
          new ProductRecall( unsafe_products );  // Oh no!
    recall->dispatch();
  }
}
```

The problem is that I'm "new"-ing a `ProductRecall` object right in the middle of my call-graph.  This violates the principles of Dependency Injection.  As written, I can't test `CheckProductSaftey()` without also creating a `ProductRecall` object.

However, I can't pass the `ProductRecall` object into my `SafetyInspector` object, because the `SafetyInspector` is the one who determines the list of unsafe products.

I'm using constructor-injection for everything, and I'd like to continue doing so.  Note also that I may issue multiple `ProductRecalls` at any time, so I can't necessarily just pass a single `ProductRecall` object into the `SafetyInspector` at construction.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You had your code embedded in <pre> tags as opposed to having it code formatted (four spaces before each line). I switched it for you so we can have the benefit of SO's pretty code coloring, but if your choice was intentional, please feel free to change it back.

Comment: Ah, ha!  I've been wondering how that works.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: No problem. When I first started here, I manually embedded everything in <code> tags. Live & learn! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be with your implementation of `ProductRecall`. Specifically, if you can call `dispatch()` on a newly created object, it implies that a lot of actual functionality is either hidden inside the `ProductRecall` class, or that the `ProductRecall` class has static members and/or singletons to give it everything else it needs.

I would recommend creating a class called `ProductRecallDispatcher` which handles the intricacies of an actual dispatch. You would then create one of these objects, and pass it to the constructor for `SafteyInspector`. This would make your `CheckProductSafety` function look as follows:

```
void SafteyInspector::CheckProductSaftey()
{
  database.getProducts( list_of_products )

  foreach( list_of_products as p )
  {
    if ( !runBatteryOfTests( p ) )
      unsafe_products.insert( p );
  }

  if ( !unsafe_products.empty() )
  {
    recallDispatcher.recall( unsafe_products );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.  You're definitely correct that there is quite a bit of complexity inside the ProductRecall object (and as you guessed, it does rely on a couple of singleton objects).  That being said -- if I create a ProductRecallDispatcher class it seems like I'm going to have the same problem inside this new object. Specifically, I'll have to "new" a ProductRecall object from inside ProductRecallDispatcher::recall().

Comment: It will depend on what the .recall() function actually does. I would suggest that most of that functionality should be moved into the dispatcher, and that a ProductRecall holds only the data associated with the actual recall, (and functions to aid in its creation). The "new"-ing would be less of a problem, since the RecallDispatcher would still own the recall object (perhaps by keeping an STL vector of pointers), and could safely dispose of it at destruction.

Comment: Incidentally, those singletons can be a problem, since using them prevents you from doing proper dependency injection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons/138012#138012

Comment: Refactoring to remove singletons and switch to dependency injection is a fun job. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually need to conjure up some sort of `ProductRecallFactory` to pass in instead.  It's fairly common for injection containers to support some sort of factory-style interface, or you may just wish to make your SafetyInspector container-aware.

EDIT: by "container-aware" I'm referring to implementing some interface along the lines of COM's `IObjectWithSite`, so that your object can call back to its parent.  It's a weaker form of dependency injection which partially undoes the inversion of control.  If you're doing the dependency injection manually, by all means inject a factory object.

Comment: Could you clarify what "container-aware" means?  (I'm using Manual DI, if it makes a difference.)